# How to organise form responses in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm trying to set up an online invitation and I have it set up so that once the form is sent, the responses get stored in a Google spreadsheet.

Here's a basic version of the invitation:
http://jsfiddle.net/ax1ncdmu/7/

Then at the bottom there's a send button which sends the info off to the spreadsheet.

My problem is that when its sent, it looks like this in the spreadsheet:

```
guest0 | guest1 | guest2 | mealChoice0 | mealChoice1 | mealChoice2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Tom    | Dick   | Harry  | Meat        | Meat        | Fish
```

Which isn't ideal, as the number of guests per invitation can change and it's hard to match up the name with their own meal choice.

Idealy, the spreadsheet would be laid out like this:

```
Name   | Meal Choice
-------|-------------
Tom    | Meat
Dick   | Meat
Harry  | Fish
```

But I'm not sure if that's even possible?  Or maybe beyond my coding knowledge...
I was trying to think whether it would be best to somehow incorporate it into multiple forms or somehow have all the names already present in the spreadsheet to reference and add on the meal choices accordingly?

Anyway, I'm open to suggestion, even if it's that it's not even possible :)

Thanks

Edit: Also, this might be useful:
http://pastebin.com/FD6QqpJQ
This is the gs script that I found which handles the data. Maybe this is what has to change, but its kinda beyond my level of coding unfortunately :/

Comment: yes its possible with script to match the right columns. however to make this a valid question you need to show your attempts and what failed. (cant code is not a valid reason as this site is for programmers)

Comment: I never said I can't code, I was just looking for advice on where to start. I've coded this entire invitation system aside from the spreadsheet part from scratch using php, js etc, i'm just not that knowledgable in the google scripts side of things. I've already explained my attempts, ie the submission works, but the formatting is not ideal. What else should i provide?

Comment: ok. but you do need to show some attempt at the problem. the parts that work are relevant but its not part of the attempt. your specific problem is about that formatting needed to later process. i asume you will be modifying the form to add more pairs of user/meal? else how? using a form per guest will be too tedious. the attempt is about determining all the column names (from 1st row) and based on that (their last letter which is a number) pair them and output the data rows in your "normalized" format on another sheet.

Comment: ok thanks, that was the exact kind of advice I was looking for. I hadn't thought of putting the data into a second sheet, but now I have a direction to head in.  I wasn't trying to get someone to do the work for me, just needed some advice on where to start.

Comment: no prob, just trying to understand where you need help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula works for your sample data - can you modify it to work with your actual sheet:

`={"Name","Meal Choice";TRANSPOSE(FILTER(2:2,IFERROR(FIND("guest",1:1),0))),TRANSPOSE(FILTER(2:2,IFERROR(FIND("meal",1:1),0)))}`

You can see it working in this sample sheet: https://goo.gl/gvsTfw

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had already found and was using the transpose function and works great for my problem.  So thought I'd just accept your answer as it's what worked for me.  Thanks also for the sample sheet!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the logic isn't optimal. Instead of having one form with fixed number por invitees, I think that will be better to have one form with three questions:

- Subject of the invitation
- Invitee name
- Meal choice

Some of advantages of the above approach are

- that the resulting answers will be displayed as expected
- the same form could be used for several events/invitations